# How can I run a node.js project on the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
var url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/";

var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    var re = new RegExp('<title>(.*)</title>');
    var r  = body.match(re);
    if (r)
        console.log(r[1]);
});
```

When I execute this command: `node index.js` I will see the result (the title of that website) in the command line environment as well. But I want to see the result in the browser. How can I do that?

Noted that months ago, I was working on a react project and If I recall correctly I was able to see the result on the browser (`localhost:3000`) by executing `npm start`. But I don't know why it doesn't happen for this project.

Comment: You required express in your code, have you tried using it?

Comment: @Luca Nope .. actually my code works well even when I remove this `var express = require('express');` line.

Comment: You need to create an app with express then listen to a port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an express server to send the response to browser.

```
var url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/";

var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('/your-route', function(req, res) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        var re = new RegExp('<title>(.*)</title>');
        var r  = body.match(re);
        if (r) {
            res.write(r[1]);
            res.end();
        }
    });
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: can you please give me an example for `/your-route` ?

Comment: anyway, your code returns `Cannot GET /` in the browser

Comment: You can replace `/your-route` with the name of your route. In your case, you can replace `/your-route` with `/` and then try to access it from the browser by typing `localhost:3000/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `socket.io`.

If you want browser run `console.log(r[1]);`, you use `socket.emit('log', r[1]);`.
In browser (in javascript of your html file):

```
socket.on('log', ...data=>{
    console.log(...data);
});
```

But you should read https://socket.io/ to config and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating an app with express

```
const express = require('express') 
const app = express() 

app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
res.send('Hello World!') 
}) 

app.listen(3000, function () { 
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!') 
})
```

Also `request` is only usefull for making http calls, not creating any kind of server

Answer (score 0):

To access anything from the browser you need to create an express app and call `listen()` on it.

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express();

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  // Process request and form a response
  response.send(/*response*/);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```